# MS Access 2007: "Attachment" data type equivalent in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2008, types

What is the "Attachment" data type's equivalent in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: It might depend on the purpose you're using the attachment field for, given that there's no 1:1 correspondence. One thing to remember, though, is that the ACE provides the attachment field type for compatibility with Sharepoint and Sharepoint data is stored in a SQL Server database, so there must actually be a data type that is most appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent the closest would be BLOB..

Answer (score 0):

Image datatype is quite similar to Attachment.

I prefer to use VarBinary(max) for images, I believe that the image datatype is supposed to e depecrated.